# i cant see my event in full calendar in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

im working on open source project in laravel ,this is a booking room system , every thing working well but there is somthing in the full calendar script where i cant see the event that i have created , but when i vew source page i see the event correctly but its not show in calendar

this is the booking index page with script code for full calendar:

```
@inject('request', 'Illuminate\Http\Request')
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h3 class="page-title">@lang('quickadmin.bookings.title')</h3>
    @can('booking_create')
    <p>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.bookings.create') }}" class="btn btn-success">@lang('quickadmin.qa_add_new')</a>

    </p>
    @endcan
         <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,700' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='https://fullcalendar.io/css/base.css?3.5.1-1.7.1-1' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.5.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />


    <div id='calendar'></div>

@stop

@section('javascript') 
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.5.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/home.js?3.5.1-1.7.1-1'></script>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
           editable: true,
           events:[
                @foreach($bookings as $booking)
                {
                    title:'{{$booking->room->name.' '.$booking->room->notes}}',    
                    start:'{{$booking->date.' '.$booking->start_time}}',
                    finish:'{{$booking->date.' '.$booking->finish_time}}',
                    url :'{{route('admin.bookings.edit',$booking->id)}}'    
                },
                @endforeach
                ] 
        })
     });

    </script>
@endsection
```

this is the Booking Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Booking;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreBookingsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\UpdateBookingsRequest;

class BookingsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of Booking.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_access')) {
            return abort(401);
        }


        if (request('show_deleted') == 1) {
            if (! Gate::allows('booking_delete')) {
                return abort(401);
            }
            $bookings = Booking::onlyTrashed()->get();
        } else {
            $bookings = Booking::all();
        }

        return view('admin.bookings.index', compact('bookings'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating new Booking.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_create')) {
            return abort(401);
        }

        $rooms = \App\Room::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');

        return view('admin.bookings.create', compact('rooms'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created Booking in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreBookingsRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreBookingsRequest $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_create')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $booking = Booking::create($request->all());



        return redirect()->route('admin.bookings.index');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing Booking.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_edit')) {
            return abort(401);
        }

        $rooms = \App\Room::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');

        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.bookings.edit', compact('booking', 'rooms'));
    }

    /**
     * Update Booking in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\UpdateBookingsRequest  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateBookingsRequest $request, $id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_edit')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);
        $booking->update($request->all());



        return redirect()->route('admin.bookings.index');
    }


    /**
     * Display Booking.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_view')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.bookings.show', compact('booking'));
    }


    /**
     * Remove Booking from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_delete')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);
        $booking->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.bookings.index');
    }

    /**
     * Delete all selected Booking at once.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function massDestroy(Request $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_delete')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        if ($request->input('ids')) {
            $entries = Booking::whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))->get();

            foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                $entry->delete();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Restore Booking from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function restore($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_delete')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $booking = Booking::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
        $booking->restore();

        return redirect()->route('admin.bookings.index');
    }

    /**
     * Permanently delete Booking from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function perma_del($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('booking_delete')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $booking = Booking::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
        $booking->forceDelete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.bookings.index');
    }
}
```

this is the Booking Model :

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * Class Booking
 *
 * @package App
 * @property string $room
 * @property string $booking_name
 * @property string $start_time
 * @property string $finish_time
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $notes
*/
class Booking extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['booking_name', 'start_time', 'finish_time', 'phone', 'email', 'notes', 'room_id'];


    /**
     * Set to null if empty
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setRoomIdAttribute($input)
    {
        $this->attributes['room_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
    }

    /**
     * Set attribute to date format
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setStartTimeAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input != null && $input != '') {
            $this->attributes['start_time'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s', $input)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } else {
            $this->attributes['start_time'] = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute from date format
     * @param $input
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStartTimeAttribute($input)
    {
        $zeroDate = str_replace(['Y', 'm', 'd'], ['0000', '00', '00'], config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');

        if ($input != $zeroDate && $input != null) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input)->format(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set attribute to date format
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setFinishTimeAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input != null && $input != '') {
            $this->attributes['finish_time'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s', $input)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } else {
            $this->attributes['finish_time'] = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute from date format
     * @param $input
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFinishTimeAttribute($input)
    {
        $zeroDate = str_replace(['Y', 'm', 'd'], ['0000', '00', '00'], config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');

        if ($input != $zeroDate && $input != null) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input)->format(config('app.date_format') . ' H:i:s');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function room()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Room::class, 'room_id')->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

this is the route of booking:

```
Route::resource('bookings', 'Admin\BookingsController');
    Route::post('bookings_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'Admin\BookingsController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'bookings.mass_destroy']);
    Route::post('bookings_restore/{id}', ['uses' => 'Admin\BookingsController@restore', 'as' => 'bookings.restore']);
    Route::delete('bookings_perma_del/{id}', ['uses' => 'Admin\BookingsController@perma_del', 'as' => 'bookings.perma_del']);
```